# using the Wii Sensor bar in a project

Tags: infrared, wii

I'd rather not destroy any of my Wii kit, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what voltage I should drive the Wii Sensor bar with if I wanted to use it as an IR transmitter for a project.

If you're feeling extra helpful, any recommendations for low power IR phototransistors which would be able to detect pulses from the bar would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7.5V according to [this link](http://www.hunterdavis.com/2011/05/04/no-solder-no-tools-no-trouble-usb-wii-sensor-bar-conversion/). Although, as far as I know the bar is literally a few infrared LEDs - the remote contains the photodiode. You could use tealights if you wanted (in a darkened room mind)

Comment: Correction, it does not have a photodiode, it's a camera. `The Wii Remote includes a 128x96 monochrome camera with built-in image processing. The camera looks through an infrared pass filter in the remote's plastic casing. The camera's built-in image processing is capable of tracking up to 4 moving objects, and these data are the only data available to the host.`

Comment: Right you are...my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The IR Leds in the Wii Sensor bar have not been identified directly, but the camera in the Wii Remote is sensitive between 850nm and 940nm, with 940nm being tracked better at farther distances. You would need a phototransistor in that range, for use with the Wii Sensor bar leds.